# Issues loading XML feed, data not showing

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Loading some xml.
Part of it looks like this:

```
<element scope="message">
   <content_type>text/plain</content_type>
   <name>Test Data 1</name>
   <content_length>369</content_length>
   <data access="text">
      YLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
   </data>
</element>
```

What I'm getting back looks like this:

```
[element] => Array
(
   [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
   (
          [@attributes] => Array
          (
                 [scope] => message
          )
          [content_type] => text/plain
          [name] => Test Data 1
          [content_length] => 369
          [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
          (
                 [@attributes] => Array
                 (
                        [access] => text
                 )
          )
    )
)
```

How can I get the  content out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access SimpleXMLElement data you must go throught it's interface. Direct access only show the instance properties as you could see.

A good starting point is the [SimpleXML documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and specially interesting for your question are the [basic examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Applied to the provided XML, you need something like this to get the `name` and the `scope` attribute:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<element scope="message">
   <content_type>text/plain</content_type>
   <name>Test Data 1</name>
   <content_length>369</content_length>
   <data access="text">
      YLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
   </data>
</element>
XML;

$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

// get data
echo $element->data;

// get attribute value
echo echo $element['scope'];
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi thank you but I'm still not sure how to get the "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" text out, I'm only getting the @attributes "text" value

Comment: Instead of $element->name use $element->data to get "Lorem..." (I've edited the code)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I get:
 SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [access] => text
        )

) not "Lorem Ipsum" returned

Comment: Which version of PHP and SimpleXML are you using? Here with PHP 5.3.10  and SimpleXML 321634 this code snippet works well.